# Is there Any better way to run a node js file in task scheduler

Tags: node.js, scheduled-tasks, windows-task-scheduler

I was trying to run a node script by task scheduler.But it gives me an error.
I have tried Cmd , git bash for script running. This command line

```
cd C:/Users/Emon/Desktop/Keepa-To-Airtable && node index.js
```

is working into the terminal but same arguments is not working into Task Scheduler.

[General](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oAnjD.png)

[action](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oPvRn.png)

[Terminal Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tDs8C.png)

I have tried to run it into Task Scheduler. But I have failed.
what whould be the proper way to execute it?

Comment: Have you tried using double quotes around the path?

Comment: @Geshode yes, I have tried it but still the same results

Comment: Also, the error image, only shows that `'eepa-To-Airtable'` as a problem. Did you maybe add a space after the K? Otherwise I wouldn't understand, why it would take that part of the path by itself.